# How to make radio button options dependent on other radio button choices using only jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, radio-button

I want to enable/disable Admin Interface options based on chosen OS
For example Ubuntu OS does not have cPanel, only Plesk etc...

[image]

I want this done using jQuery, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this

```js
    $("input[name='os']").change(function (){
        $("input[name='backend']").attr("checked", false);
        $("input[name='backend']").attr("disabled",false);
        $("#"+$(this).attr("relatedto")).attr("disabled",true);
    });
```

```html
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <input name="os" type="radio" relatedto="interface1">Os1<br/>
    <input name="os" type="radio" relatedto="interface1">Os2<br/>
    <input name="os" type="radio" relatedto="interface2">Os3<br/>
    <input name="os" type="radio" relatedto="interface2">Os4<br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <hr/>
    <input name="backend" type="radio" id="interface1">cpanel<br/>
    <input name="backend" type="radio" id="interface2">cpanel<br/>
```